# There are curly braces in my COBOL output

Tags: cobol

My output in my latest 85 program has displays curly braces after the variables and im wondering why this is.

ex: - TOTALS: BEGN-BAL:00100000{ PAYMNT:0000300{ PURCHS:0002500{ FIN-CHRGE:001659{

Comment: Those are signed display (PIC S9(8)) numbers.  You need to change them to PIC ZZ,ZZZ,ZZ9 display numbers.

Comment: a classic... Thanks Gilbert.

Comment: probably should use --,---,--9 otherwise you will not know if it is negative

Comment: @Bruce Martin: Good general advice, but { is positive zero, and } is negative zero.  :-)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc only a "negative zero" in the sense that the right-most digit in a negative number is zero. Other than through perversity or by incompetence, a negative-zero value cannot exist in an IBM COBOL. I'm guessing it is an IBM COBOL, since it is an EBCDIC value for the curly-brackets which is being shown. In the PICture you suggest, all values will show as positive, which is the point Bruce was making.

Answer (score 0):

actually

{ -> indicates +ve sign and

} -> indicates -ve sign

example: for +10 -->in program take s9(02) --> output:  " 1{ "

example:   for -10--> in program  take s9(02) output-> " 1} "

SIGN - WILL BE STORE IN LAST DIGIT AS A CHARACTERS.